# Comparing 1 value to single array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, string-comparison, comparison-operators

How to comparing one value to every single value in the particular array?

For example:

```
$list =  ("blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "orange", "white");
$value = "blue";

if ($value == $list)
{
  // then print "This is BLUE";
}
```

I need only one time to determine the colors, no need repeating to print other color.

This may bring me to implement a dynamic value retrieved from database, and then comparing a [hardcode] array in PHP script. Then, return the exact value match onto the screen, example as above scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you be looking for [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)?

```
if (in_array('blue', $colors)) {
    // the color blue is there
}
```

Comment: It was an amazing answer without example. Each developer, especially newbie should know where the documentation is and how to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) ?

```
$list =  array("blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "orange", "white");
$value = "blue";

if (in_array($value, $list))
{
  // then print "This is BLUE";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$list = array("blue","orange","green");
$value = "blue";

if(in_array($value, $list)) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` is the function you should use when comparing a single value to an array,
**but** if you need to compare **more than one value** to an array,  you may create a new array of the values you've got and then use `array_intersect($array1,$array2)`